# WordPress Custom Post Type Navigation + Children

Tags: custom-post-types

UPDATED: 5/08/2010

WordPress has now added an additional technique to display the items from a custom post-type if the post-type is set to Hierarchical.

What I would like to do though is make it so the post items have the .current_page_item class when selected in the navigation.

Does anyone know of a function to achieve this?

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
      'post_type'=>'testimonials',
      'title_li'=> __('Testimonials')
    );
    wp_list_pages( $args ); 
    ?>
```

Thanks,
George

Comment: Can you please leave some feedback if/why the solution in the answer by Justen is working or not for you?

Answer (score 1):

seen your tweet and thought i'd lend a hand, its been a while since i've coded WP - but heres my attempt: http://pastebin.com/MZiycrMe

how i go about it is,

- get all top level pages
- loop around each top level page checking for children
- add all of the above into a multi dimension array
- loop over the multi dimension array to build unordered list

i was going from the top of my head and the WP docs so there *might* be a bug or two, but the logic is sound..

give me a shout if you want a hand to implement it..

Justen